# Can you reference a static resource from another package

Tags: visualforce, static-resources, react

I'm building a base managed packaged as well as an extension managed packaged. I have a static resource in the base packaged (a react resource) and would like to include it on a VisualForce page in the extension package..

When I use a declaration like this in my extension VF page

```
<script type="text/babel" src="{! URLFOR($Resource.<base_package_namespace__ReactSObjectDetailJSX) }" />
```

I get the following error. Is there anyway to reference a static resource from one package from a different package?

[image]

Comment: is your static resource marked as `Public` or `Private`?

Comment: it was marked public, but I ended up just pulling the resource into my local package to solve it..